# (PYTHON) Randint spouting errors

Tags: python, python-3.x

so the randint is causing a problem, everything else works, but when I try to randomize the time.sleep interval it just spouts errors. I'm pretty new to coding so I don't quite understand the error. (Error is below the code)

```
from pyautogui import *
from time import sleep
import keyboard
import win32api, win32con
import random


def autoclick():
    while keyboard.is_pressed('r') == True:

        win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN,0,0)
        sleep(0.01)
        win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP,0,0)

        cpsmin = 0.10 / 1.25 # NUO KIEK CLICKU
        cpsmax = 0.12 / 1.25 # IKI KIEK CLICKU
        randomizeclicks = random.randint(cpsmin, cpsmax)

        sleep(randomizeclicks)

print('RUNNING')
while keyboard.is_pressed('z') == False:
    if keyboard.is_pressed('r') == True:
        autoclick()
    sleep(0.5)
```

The error code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\_Python_Projects\autoclicker.py", line 24, in <module>
    autoclick()
  File "d:\_Python_Projects\autoclicker.py", line 17, in autoclick
    randomizeclicks = random.randint(cpsmin, cpsmax)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\random.py", line 339, in randint
    return self.randrange(a, b+1)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\random.py", line 303, in randrange
    raise ValueError("non-integer arg 1 for randrange()")
ValueError: non-integer arg 1 for randrange()
```

Comment: The stacktrace is saying it all.

Answer (score 1):

you are passing floats while only integers are allowed as input for randint